# Limit leading Fs in Excel DEC2HEX with negative numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to convert decimal numbers to 8 bit 2s complement hex.

- When I do `DEC2HEX(1,2)` I get `01` which is perfect.
- When I do `DEC2HEX(-1,2)` I get `FFFFFFFFFF` which is way too many.

How do I limit the output of `DEC2HEX(-1,2)` to just `FF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Excel's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DEC2HEX-function-6344ee8b-b6b5-4c6a-a672-f64666704619):

> **If number is negative, `places` is ignored** and `DEC2HEX` returns a 10-character (40-bit) hexadecimal number in which the most significant bit is the sign bit. The remaining 39 bits are magnitude bits. Negative numbers are represented using two's-complement notation.

So you have to truncate the value yourself

```
=RIGHT(DEC2HEX(-1, 2), 2)
```

or

```
=DEC2HEX(IF(A1 < 0, A1 + 256, A1), 2)
```

Another solution is

```
=DEC2HEX(BITAND(A1 + 256, 255), 2)
```

The `+ 256` part is for converting the negative value to its 2's complement. This works only for 8-bit numbers. For arbitrary n-bit 2's complement numbers you need to use `+ 2^n`